# xsl for-each outputs all data rather than one at a time

Tags: xml, xslt

Want to preface this by saying I have 0 experience with XML/XSL, and am not familiar with the terminology I should be using.

I'm working on code that uses an xml file. The xml file (the important parts I guess) is formatted something like this:

```
<All> 
  <Cases> 
    <Case> 
      <extension-fields> 
        <extension-field display-text="whatever"> 
          <value>X</value> 
        </extension-field> 
      </extension-fields> 
    </Case>  
    <Case> 
      <extension-fields> 
        <extension-field display-text="whatever"> 
          <value>Y</value> 
        </extension-field> 
      </extension-fields> 
    </Case> 
  </Cases> 
</All>
```

Each case has its own set of extension fields.

I'm trying to pull individual extension-field value where the display-text = 'whatever' for each of my Cases. The way I've written this is the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="All/Cases/Case">
  <w:tc> 
    <w:tcPr> 
      <w:tcW w:w="{$Col2}" w:type="dxa"/>  
      <w:vAlign w:val="top"/> 
    </w:tcPr>  
    <w:p> 
      <w:pPr> 
        <w:jc w:val="right"/> 
      </w:pPr>  
      <w:r> 
        <w:t> 
          <xsl:value-of select="/All/Cases/Case/extension-fields/extension-field[@display-text = 'whatever']/value"/> 
        </w:t> 
      </w:r> 
    </w:p> 
  </w:tc>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(this is shoved somewhere in a table and I wasn't sure if it was all relevant so I just showed the whole part I'm having trouble with)

I'm expecting to see each Case's individual values in the output (so each case number will have the its X and Y value next to it) but instead, I'm seeing every single case has both values X Y next to it. Now what I think's happening is the for-each on the case, each matter is looping through the whole  part rather than the individual case, but I'm having trouble figuring out why.

Comment: Just to expand on @Alejandro's answer says: your selection within the for-each should be relative to the current node, rather than an absolute selection from the document root. You want `select="extension-fields/extension-field[@display-text = 'whatever']/value"`

Answer (score 0):

> *Now what I think's happening is the for-each on the case, each matter is looping through the whole part rather than the individual case, but
>   I'm having trouble figuring out why.*

Your context in `xsl:for-each` instruction's content template is a `Case` element, but your `xsl:value-of` instruction use an absolute location path (`/All/Cases/Case/extension-fields/extension-field[@display-text = 'whatever']/value`). That will always have the same result for any input source disregarding the current context node because... it's an [absolute location path](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AbsoluteLocationPath).